# Wilcoxon p-value correction for extremely small samples

Tags: wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, false-discovery-rate

I have performed thousands of Wilcoxon test. Unfortunately, for some of the tests size of one of the groups was equal to 1 or 2.

```
pvals <- rep(0, 100000)
for (i in 1:length(pvals)) {
one_sample <- rnorm(1)
two_sample <- rnorm(70)
pvals[i] <- wilcox.test(one_sample, two_sample, alternative = "greater")$p.value
}

hist(pvals)
```

These p-values can not be corrected for FDR using conventional methods since the distribution is not uniform.

How can I overcome this super-small sample size limitation and make the distribution of p-values uniform? The easiest way would be to say: that's not how Wilcoxon test works, but, unfortunately, I have data and have to work with it...Should I replace Wilcoxon with some bootstrap analogue?

Comment: The bootstrap will not solve this problem.  And you seem to be taking for granted that FDR is a good idea in your context.  The value of FDR will depend on the false negative probability and on your goals.  But no matter what you may trouble in the limiting case where the sample size is one in a sample.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! To avoid the issues with the false negative probability I, in general, estimate FDR as 2 * (number of p-values > 0.5) and the variance of the samples is not big, but I rely on uniformity in similar-to-BH-correction analysis. But I see, there is no good solution for this and I should not spend more time on it...

Comment: The distribution of p-values is never continuous uniform for a discrete test statistic (and usually not discrete uniform either).

Comment: That's the problem, but I still have rely on at least rough approximation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wilcox.test function by default seems to use an asymptotic approximation for computing the p-values, which in cases with one very small group isn't good. If you run it with exact=TRUE, it computes exact p-values, which is computer intensive in general, but not if one group has 1 or 2 observations. (I tried out your code with exact=TRUE and uniformity is much better, although the histogram may look a bit weird, probably for reasons of discreteness.)

Comment: oh thank you thank you =) you saved my day. for me histogram looks perfect, when number of breaks increased.